# Ruby Array#transpose real world example

Tags: ruby

Does anyone have a real-world example of a situation where Array#transpose would be useful? I'm struggling to relate the functionality to possible applications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Array%23transpose+is%3Aanswer+%5Bruby%5D

Comment: One often has the choice of using [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) or [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip). Suppose, for example, `a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` and you wish to obtain `[1+3+5, 2+4+6] #=> [9,12]`. You could do that like this: `a.transpose.map { |c| c.reduce(:+) } #=> [9,12]` or `a.first.zip(*a[1..-1]).map { |c| c.reduce(:+) } #=> [9,12]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
class Array
  def mean
    reduce(:+) / length
  end
end

locations = [
  [41.311000, -96.138319],
  [41.311355, -96.130380],
  [41.315319, -96.138319],
  [41.316093, -96.129994],
  [41.317640, -96.124372],
  [41.315964, -96.121883],
  [41.313128, -96.121968],
  [41.313160, -96.125101],
  [41.309775, -96.125316]
]

latitudes, longitudes = locations.transpose

puts latitudes.inspect
# => [41.311, 41.311355, 41.315319, 41.316093, ...

puts longitudes.inspect
# => [-96.138319, -96.13038, -96.138319, -96.129994 ...

weighted_center = [latitudes.mean, longitudes.mean]

puts weighted_center.inspect
# => [41.31371488888889, -96.12840577777779]
```

[`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) can be thought of as the opposite of [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-zip)

Comment: Thanks Carl! Nice lake. Now I have to go there. :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful if you had a collection of names. The first element might be a first name and the second element might be a last name.

You might want to get a list of the first names or the last names

```
names = [["John", "Smith"],["Roger", "Jones"]]
```

You could get the first names by calling `names.transpose.first`